# Adding and using header (HTTP) in nginx

Tags: nginx, http, http-headers

I am using two system (both are nginx load balancer and one act as an backup).  I want to add and use few http custom headers. Please give your suggestion

e.g

```
  upstream upstream0{
            #list of upstream servers
            server backend:80;
            server backup_load_balancer:777 backup;
            #healthcheck
  }

  server{
        listen  80;
        #Add custom header about the port and protocol  (http or https)
        server_name     _;
        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://upstream0;#" is included since links are not allowed in the post
        }

   }
```

//Backup system

```
server{
        listen  777;
        server_name     _;
        #doing some other extra stuf

        #use port and protocol to direct
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add headers then you want something like this:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     _;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    add_header X-Your-Port-Header-Here $server_port;
    add_header X-Your-Protocol-Header-Here $scheme;
    set $yourcustomheader $scheme$server_port;
    add_header X-Your-Custom-Header $yourcustomheader;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://upstream0;
    }

}
```

You can reference the following [variables in Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables). If the above doesn't provide enough flexibility for you then take a look at the [HttpHeadersMore](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module, but note that is *not* provided in most standard Nginx distributions so you may have to compile it yourself. If you use Debian, though, then you can find it in the [nginx-extras](https://docs.google.com/a/moolfreet.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjuNPnOoex7SdG5fUkhfc3BCSjJQbVVrQTg4UGU2YVE#gid=0) package from [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/).